# How to access VMWare filesystem with .NET means

Tags: .net, vmware, mount

In my C# 3.5 program I would like to access a NTFS/FAT drives from VMWare virtual machine. I have vmdk file with Windows 7 inside.

Is there any programmatic way to mount such drives from vmdk file and access them with the regular .NET API like File.ReadAllText, Directory.GetDirectories and so on?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to mount the virtual machine disk image (.vmdk) using VMWARE Disk MOunt utility - then you should be able to access it like any other drive - there are some caveats regarding disk snapshots - found some more info [here](http://www.petri.co.il/virtual_mount_vmware_virtual_disk_without_vmware.htm)

The utility has a command line interface so it should be possible to use Process.Start() to execute the mount operation

Comment: Thanks, Richard. If there is no other API to mount the image, I will use your advice.